# Why master user that was created when configuring RDS has no sysadmin role on created server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've started **RDS SQL Server**. At that moment a master user was created as well. I can connect to my SQL server with **SQL management studio**. The question is why doesn't my user have `sysadmin` role?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its one of the tradeoffs when using SQL Server on RDS, you don't get complete administrator-level access to the server.

This page tells you the restrictions you will have:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

[image]